# Cohen's Kappa - extreme disagreement doesn't register as strongly as extreme agreement

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I'm wondering why, for the following data, the Kappa statistic wasn't $\pm 1$ but instead $-0.95$ for complete disagreement and $1$ for complete agreement.

I expected them to have the same value.

Data in agreement : 
$$
\begin{array}
&&0&1\\ 
 0 & 294 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 406 \\
\end{array} 
$$

Data in disagreement : 
$$
\begin{array}
&&0&1\\ 
 0 & 0 & 294 \\
1 & 406 & 0 \\
\end{array} 
$$

Code :

```
library(caret)
# complete disagreement
r1 <- c(rep(0,294) , rep(1, 406) )
r2 <- 1 - r1
confusionMatrix(table(r1,r2))
# complete agreement 
r1 <- c(rep(0,294) , rep(1, 406) )
r2 <- r1
confusionMatrix(table(r1,r2))
```

## Edit - equal margins

The following code returns the same statistic for each extreme

```
library(caret)
zero = 294
ones = 294
# complete disagreement
r1 <- c(rep(0,zero) , rep(1, ones) )
r2 <- 1 - r1
confusionMatrix(table(r1,r2))
# complete agreement 
r1 <- c(rep(0,zero) , rep(1, ones) )
r2 <- r1
confusionMatrix(table(r1,r2))
```

New data is

Data in agreement : 
$$
\begin{array}
&&0&1\\ 
 0 & 294 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 294 \\
\end{array} 
$$

Data in disagreement : 
$$
\begin{array}
&&0&1\\ 
 0 & 0 & 294 \\
1 & 294 & 0 \\
\end{array} 
$$

Comment: `confusionMatrix` is not a function in the distribution of R. Are you using the one in `caret` or one from some other package?

Comment: @Glen_b yes sorry, I've added that to the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cohen's kappa only attains the extremes of $+1$ or $-1$ when the totals are the same for both margins.

This is true for the margins in your first table - both are ($294,406$) in that order - but not for the second - one is ($294,406$) and the other is ($406,294$). This will cause the kappa measure to not quite get down to $-1$.

See what happens if they're both (say) $294$.

Similar issues occur with many measures of association in contingency tables (where sometimes the extremes are not attained, even though you might expect they should).

Comment: Thanks, is there anything that should be of concern as a result here? It seems that similar margins make the result "stronger", I'm not sure how to comment on that though.

Comment: Note - if that comment of mine overlaps with another post I'd be happy to read it, I'm not sure how to find such a post though

Comment: It's a non-intuitive outcome, for sure. It's a property to be aware of but not automatically something to be concerned about (unless you're putting interpretations on it it can't support). Many measures of association and agreement and correlation on tables have similar issues; it's hard to make a measure that satisfies all our expectations on categorical variables.

Comment: fair enough - I'm using it in something and was unsure about whether I should comment on this aspect of it. I was originally pointing out that $\chi^2$ didn't account for agreement but association (with a two way table), and met this margin thing whilst creating an example for that. I'll just use an example with equal margins though. Thanks

Comment: I'd certainly be inclined to mention it if I thought readers would be likely to be unaware of it.

Comment: Yes - I'm not sure what I'd really refer to it as other than pointing out that it's a thing. Does this have a name? Marginal balance, or something like that

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for it, sorry.